# Would this question be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

There was a vulnerability in Tor Browser not long ago. After updates it was  enabling javascript automatically *without any warning whatsoever*.

I want to find out whether it was intentional or not. Is a question asking whether it could have been intentional on-topic here?

If not:

- is there a site (SE or otherwise) where such a question would be on topic?
- can I ask or even pay someone to find out
- is it possible to search it on my own? (what should I be looking for?)

My problem is I can't even [find](https://gitweb.torproject.org/builders/tor-browser-build.git/plain/projects/tor-browser/Bundle-Data/Docs/ChangeLog.txt?h=maint-8.0) when the bug was fixed.

Comment: I doubt that we could know if it was intentional, which means we would be speculating

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Tor Stack Exchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/) site for questions specific to Tor. While asking whether or not a certain design change in Tor was intentional is off-topic for this site, it would be fine on the Tor site.

Comment: Tor was my initial thought but seeing 0 comments and answers in a [related question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/17795/noscript-enabled-automatically-by-tor-browser-updates) i doubt anyone would know.

Comment: @Fermiparadox You _could_ try to ask on the mailing list or on IRC.